# Display text below an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-imageview, textview

In `Xamarin`, I have a `ViewPager` that has some fragments, where each fragment displays a simple `Bitmap` in an `ImageView`.

I am needing to add some text below each of these images for each fragment.

Here is my current `ViewPagerItemWithImage` layout code for each fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the relevant `OnCreateView` code:

```
rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewPagerItemWithImage, container, false);
imageView = rootView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
DownloadAsyncBitmap (imageURI, imageView);
imageView.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.Center);
```

May I have some help to write some code similar to the above code, but instead with some text displayed below the `ImageView`?

Here is what I have so far:

`ViewPagerItemWithImageAndText` layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="This is an image"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`OnCreateView` code:

```
rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewPagerItemWithImageAndText, container, false);
imageView = rootView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
textView = rootView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.myImageViewText);
DownloadAsyncBitmap (imageURI, imageView);
```

The text is not being shown at all.

May I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="8"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="7"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is an image"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: for `ViewPagerItemWithImageAndText layout code:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="This is an image"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below property will arrange your item vertically hence your textview will also become below of Image.

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: I still cannot see the text. Is this anything to do with ImageView:layout_height="match_parent"?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning match_parent width and height to your imageview dur to which textview will not get space to be shown in layout change height of image view to some value or alternatively use framelayout but that will display text as overlay on imageview.
Use this code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot format this XML code correctly, I am getting an invalid XML error...